# Attachment action sheet hidden behind keyboard in iOS 9

Tags: uiactionsheet

If the keyboard is shown in the chat view controller and you tap the photo attachment button, the action sheet for the photo options is hidden behind the keyboard. If the keyboard is hidden/dismissed and you tap the photo button, you can see the action sheet just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call  this method

[self.view endEditing:YES];